# Lightbox Javascript not working for imgs

Tags: javascript, php, html, lightbox

Attached below is a php script I have and for some reason I cannot get Lightbox - Lokesh Dhakar to work. I have tried countless different arrangements in syntax and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I even tried to add the lightbox javascript at the end of the body just in case but no luck. Any suggestions you guys have for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>CCTV</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/img/favicon-32x32.png">

        <!-- STYLES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/css/style.css">




        <!-- SCRIPTS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/js/directorylister.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/js/iscroll.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>




        <!-- FONTS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono">

        <!-- META -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script type="text/javascript">



        </script>



    </head>
<body>
<!--    <body onload="loaded()"> -->

        <div id="page-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <?php $breadcrumbs = $lister->listBreadcrumbs(); ?>

                <p class="navbar-text">
                    <?php foreach($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb): ?>
                        <?php if ($breadcrumb != end($breadcrumbs)): ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['link']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
                                <span class="divider">/</span>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </p>


            </div>
        </div>




        <div id="page-content" class="container">

            <?php file_exists('header.php') ? include('header.php') : include($lister->getThemePath(true) . "/default_header.php"); ?>

            <?php if($lister->getSystemMessages()): ?>
                <?php foreach ($lister->getSystemMessages() as $message): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $message['type']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $message['text']; ?>
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <h3 style="text-align: center; margin: 1em;" > Ardor | home ~ CCTV </h3>

        <div id="wrapper">


            <ul id="directory-listing" class="row nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

            <?php $counter = 0;?>   


                <?php foreach( array_slice( $dirArray, 1 ) as $name => $fileInfo): ?>



                    <li>

                        <div class="col-md-4 thumbs">

                        <a href="<?php echo $fileInfo['url_path']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery" >

                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $fileInfo['url_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fileInfo['url_path']; ?>" >  </a>

                                <p> <?php echo $name; ?> </p>

                                </div>



                    </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </ul>

                    </div> 

        </div> 

        <?php file_exists('footer.php') ? include('footer.php') : include($lister->getThemePath(true) . "/default_footer.php"); ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/css/lightbox.min.css">

    </body>

</html>
```

Output Below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>CCTV</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/themes/bootstrap/img/favicon-32x32.png">

        <!-- STYLES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/themes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/themes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/themes/bootstrap/css/style.css">




        <!-- SCRIPTS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/themes/bootstrap/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/themes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/themes/bootstrap/js/directorylister.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/themes/bootstrap/js/iscroll.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/themes/bootstrap/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>




        <!-- FONTS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono">

        <!-- META -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script type="text/javascript">



        </script>



    </head>
<body>
<!--    <body onload="loaded()"> -->

        <div id="page-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">


                <p class="navbar-text">
                                                                            <a href="http://monitor.capa.furniture/">Home</a>
                                <span class="divider">/</span>
                                                                                                    <a href="http://monitor.capa.furniture/?dir=dynasty_loop">dynasty_loop</a>
                                <span class="divider">/</span>
                                                                                                snap                                                            </p>


            </div>
        </div>




        <div id="page-content" class="container">



            <h3 style="text-align: center; margin: 1em;" > Ardor | home ~ CCTV </h3>

        <div id="wrapper">


            <ul id="directory-listing" class="row nav nav-pills nav-stacked">







                    <li>

                        <div class="col-md-4 thumbs">

                        <a href="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_19_11_53_59550.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" >

                        <img class="img-responsive" src="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_19_11_53_59550.jpg" alt="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_19_11_53_59550.jpg" >  </a>

                                <p> SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_19_11_53_59550.jpg </p>

                                </div>



                    </li>




                    <li>

                        <div class="col-md-4 thumbs">

                        <a href="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_18_41_16_57085.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" >

                        <img class="img-responsive" src="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_18_41_16_57085.jpg" alt="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_18_41_16_57085.jpg" >  </a>

                                <p> SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_18_41_16_57085.jpg </p>

                                </div>



                    </li>




                    <li>

                        <div class="col-md-4 thumbs">

                        <a href="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_17_58_53_4731.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" >

                        <img class="img-responsive" src="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_17_58_53_4731.jpg" alt="dynasty_loop/snap/SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_17_58_53_4731.jpg" >  </a>

                                <p> SNAP_CH03_2016_01_06_17_58_53_4731.jpg </p>

                                </div>



                    </li>






            </ul>

                    </div> 

        </div> 

        <hr>

<div class="footer">
    Powered by, <a href="http://www.directorylister.com">Directory Lister</a>
</div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/themes/bootstrap/css/lightbox.min.css">

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: Have you checked the script `src` URLs that are actually generated in your HTML and verified they are correct?

Comment: You should post the generated HTML rather than the PHP source

Comment: Okay, I added the output above.

Comment: There are no console errors and all get requests are fulfilled. I cannot wrap my mind around this.

Comment: Having a look at this site: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started it appears that you have not included the css file.

Comment: I just added this and not luck still.  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/css/lightbox.min.css">`